# Making a NaN on purpose in WebGL

Tags: glsl, webgl, nan

I have a GLSL shader that's supposed to output NaNs when a condition is met. I'm having trouble actually making that happen.

Basically I want to do this:

```
float result = condition ? NaN : whatever;
```

But GLSL doesn't seem to have a constant for NaN, so that doesn't compile. **How do I make a NaN?**

---

I tried making the constant myself:

```
float NaN = 0.0/0.0; // doesn't work
```

That works on one of the machines I tested, but not on another. Also it causes warnings when compiling the shader.

Given that the obvious computation didn't work on one of the machines I tried, I get the feeling that doing this correctly is quite tricky and involves knowing a lot of real-world facts about the inconsistencies between various types of GPUs.

Comment: Why do you want to generate a NaN value? Every stage of the shader pipeline is expected to generate a valid result for its stage

Comment: @ibesora I'm using webgl to simulate a quantum circuit, and NaN is how I signal an error condition during an aggregation step. [Here's the specific shader that's causing trouble](https://github.com/Strilanc/Quirk/blob/efb797b9bd48f2dc46deadade17e883b00fffc26/src/gates/AmplitudeDisplayFamily.js#L311).

Comment: Maybe a uniform with NaN supplied?

Comment: @TamasHegedus I was actually just about to add that as a possible answer. If you know it works across various GPUs, then that's what I'll go with.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a single nvidia 840m at hand, can't test it on multiple devices. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Don't use NaNs here.**

Section 2.3.4.1 from the [OpenGL ES 3.2 Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/es_spec_3.2.pdf) states that

> The special values Inf and −Inf encode values with magnitudes too large to be represented; the special value NaN encodes “Not A Number” values resulting from undefined arithmetic operations such as 0/0. Implementations are permitted, **but not required**, to support Inf's and NaN's in their floating-point computations.

So it seems to really depend on implementation. You should be outputing another value instead of NaN

Comment: Hmm, well that's extremely inconvenient. Very useful to know, though.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WebGL. WebGL is not based on OpenGL. It's based on OpenGL ES. If you're quoting a spec please quote the correct spec.

Comment: You are right @gman, although both specs describe the same behaviour, I changed the spec link to the OpenGL ES one.

Answer (score 1):

**Pass it in as a uniform**

Instead of trying to make the NaN in glsl, make it in javascript then pass it in:

```
shader = ...
    uniform float u_NaN
    ...

call shader with "u_NaN" set to NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fool the Optimizer**

It seems like the issue is the shader compiler performing an incorrect optimization. Basically, it replaces a `NaN` expression with `0.0`. I have no idea *why* it would do that... but it does. Maybe the spec allows for undefined behavior?

Based on that assumption, I tried making an obfuscated method that produces a `NaN`:

```
float makeNaN(float nonneg) {
    return sqrt(-nonneg-1.0);
}

...
    float NaN = makeNaN(some_variable_I_know_isnt_negative);
```

The idea is that the optimizer isn't clever enough to see through this.
And, on the test machine that was failing, this works! I also tried simplifying the function to just return `sqrt(-1.0)`, but that brought back the failure (further reinforcing my belief that the optimizer is at fault).

**This is a workaround, not a solution**.

1. A sufficiently clever optimizer could see through the obfuscation and start breaking things again.
2. I only tested it in a couple machines, and this is clearly something that varies a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity glsl compiler will convert `0.0f/0.0f` to `intBitsToFloat(int(0xFFC00000u)` - since `intBitsToFloat` is supported from OpenGL ES 3.0 onwards, this is a solution that works in WebGL2 but not WebGL1

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but intBitsToFloat(-1) should also work (also you're missing a closing brackets there)